# Does code inside @{...} run on form submit or all time

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and currently looking at tutorials on `w3school`.

What I come across that I do not understand is this code:

```
@{
var imagePath=""; 
if( Request["Choice"] != null)
   {imagePath="images/" + Request["Choice"];} 
} 

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Display Images</h1> 
        <form method="post" action=""> 
            I want to see: 
            <select name="Choice"> 
                <option value="Pic1.jpg">Photo 1</option> 
                <option value="Pic2.jpg">Photo 2</option> 
                <option value="Pic3.jpg">Photo 3</option> 
             </select> 
             <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
             @if(imagePath != "")
             {
                 <p>
                 <img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample">
                 </p>
             }  
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What confuses me is this part `@if(imagePath != "")`

My question is does that part of code runs all time (so it goes every Xms through all code inside page) or does it run when user click `submit`

Also if it runs when user click submit, how does it know what part of code to run since this code `action=""` is empty so how does it know if it needs to run first block or second one

Comment: Neither. It runs when the view is rendered on the server, before the page is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Then how is `submit` button rendering image from that code? - [example link](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/showfile_c.asp?filename=try_webpages_cs_010)

Comment: it runs when your page loads. it calculates the value of the `imagePath` variable, then that value is injected into the resulting HTML via `<img src="@imagePath"` The `@` in Razor syntax indicates to the Razor engine that what follows is it to be interpreted as server-side code to execute, rather than static content to directly render. In summary, the C# code runs on the server and is used to help build the HTML content which the server then sends to be browser to be displayed. The resulting content is a mixture of the output from the C# and the static HTML written directly into the view.

Comment: Maybe you should take the introductory MVC or Razor Pages tutorials provided by Microsoft, they might be of better quality than w3schools - that site can be useful sometimes but it is also notorious for containing silly mistakes or incomplete explanations. Another aside: If you wanted some code which would run in the browser, after the page is already being displayed to the user, then you'd need JavaScript for that.

Comment: `@{ ... }` defines Razor code block, it always rendered server-side every time the page is loaded. If you want to run client-side code in certain interval after entire DOM elements are ready, use JS instead.

Comment: @ADyson well basically I need to make some app for web and since I am working with `c#, .NET, winform` I wanted to use `C#`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto so since `action` is blank it points to current file and since `submit` is pressed it refreshes page and start Razor code?

Comment: @AleksaRistic by all means you can use C# on the server, and create a working web application, but if you want to make a modern, user-friendly, more interactive web application in the style of sites like this one and most others, you'd need to learn JavaScript as well. It's not 100% essential for creating a web application but it makes a huge difference to what you can get your application to do.

Comment: " so since action is blank it points to current file and since submit is pressed it refreshes page and start Razor code? –"....yes, but remember the Razor code executed once already when the page first loaded. Is it clear now?

Comment: @ADyson could you provide me with good tutorials or to go old fashioned  MSDN?

Comment: @ADyson it is clear. I got that part

Comment: Strictly, it's off-topic to recommend 3rd-party tutorials on this site, but assuming you want to use MVC then the Microsoft ones are obvious, and a good place to start: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x (note this uses ASP.NET Core, which is Microsoft's newer version of ASP.NET). Or there's Razor Pages instead: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . You should search about MVC and Razor pages and decide which framework best suits your purpose.

Comment: @AleksaRistic All server-side codes are executed immediately after `return View()` starts rendering view page. Afterwards, if you want to communicate with server again, you need either using callback (AJAX) from client-side code or postback (form submission) with `HttpPost` method.